# How to distinguish between the different frequency domains?

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

Sometimes the terms 'Fourier domain', 'complex frequency domain', 'Frequency domain' and 's domain' are used interchangeably.

Take those answers here for example: 
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090924230321AAxvnJg

Can you really use them interchangeably all the time, without being technically wrong?
So, could you describe what would be wrong if I would replace 'complex frequency domain' by 'fourier domain' for example? Or replacing 'complex frequency domain' by 'frequency domain'?

Answer (score 1):

"Fourier domain" and "frequency domain" are sometimes used interchangeably, depending on the field. In engineering and signal processing, one often encounters "frequency domain". However, this is a bit of a blanket term, because this can refer more broadly to a domain encountered through some spectral transform that need not necessarily be a Fourier transform (such as a periodogram, which is essentially, but not quite, a Fourier transform), or which need not go through the complex plane.

Comment: What are the exact differences between Fourier domain and s domain?